# function type vs. function pointer type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the difference between the following two blocks of code:

```
void f(int (*func)(int))
{
    func(5);
}
```

and

```
void g(int (func)(int))
{
    func(5);
}
```

Both functions work in the same way given the following code:

```
int blah(int a)
{
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    f(blah);
    g(blah);

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I write the following code:

```
int (*foo)(int);
int (goo)(int);
foo = blah;
goo = blah;
```

I get a compile error for **goo = blah**. But in the first example, I could call make the function call **g(blah)** which appears to be quite similar to **goo = blah**. Why does one work and not the other?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly, you can declare a function to take a function as a parameter (even though that makes no sense), and the effect is to make the parameter a function pointer. This is similar to the way you can declare a function parameter that looks like an array, but is actually a pointer.

The function argument can be the name of the function, with or without a `&` to explicitly take its address. If you omit the `&`, then there's an implicit function-to-pointer conversion. Again, this is similar to passing a (pointer to) an array, where the implicit array-to-pointer conversion means you only need to write the array's name, rather than `&array[0]`.

That rule doesn't apply when declaring variables; `int goo(int);` (with or without unnecessary parentheses around `goo`) declares a function, not a pointer, and you can't assign to functions.

Comment: @Deduplicator: No, because that would be incorrect. They're just sometimes not needed due to the implicit conversions. (Sadly, banning the implicit conversions isn't an option without breaking 30+ years of legacy code).

Comment: @Deduplicator: Indeed, the implicit conversions mean that you usually don't need the operators, and that their effect is sometimes implicitly undone. It would still be wrong to say that they have no effect, since they do.

Comment: But `*` *does* have an effect: it dereferences the pointer to give an expression of function type (again, it's just explicitly does what the implicit conversion does; but you can't say it has no effect at all, since it does).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are these rules written somewhere in the C/C++ standards?

Answer (score 5):

It's analogous to the difference between an array and a pointer, e.g. if you have:

```
char *foo;
char bar[N];
```

you can do:

```
foo = bar;
```

but you can't do:

```
bar = foo;
```

When the function type is used in an argument declaration, it's translated to the equivalent function pointer, just as declaring:

```
void fun(int arr[]);
```

is translated to:

```
void fun(int *arr);
```