# function type vs pointer to function type in template specialization

Tags: c++, function, templates, language-lawyer, function-pointers

I apologize in advanced because this is most probably a duplicate as I see several questions revolving around this idea (see below) but they didn't make my ideas clearer about the properties of function type or function pointer type, with respect to templates.

Here is a snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int square(int x) { return x * x; }

template <typename R, typename... P>
void Match(R foo(P...)) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pointer<decltype(foo)>::value
              << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same<int (*)(int), decltype(foo)>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<int(int), decltype(foo)>::value
              << '\n';
    std::cout << "Match matched a function\n";
}
template <typename R, typename... P>
void MatchPtr(R (*foo)(P...)) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pointer<decltype(foo)>::value
              << '\n';
    std::cout << "MatchPtr matched a pointer to function\n";
}
template <typename T>
struct Matcher {};
template <typename R, typename... P>
struct Matcher<R(P...)> {
    using T = R(P...);
    static void Disp() {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pointer<T>::value << '\n';
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<R(P...), T>::value << '\n';
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<R (*)(P...), T>::value
                  << '\n';
        std::cout << "Matcher matched a function\n";
    }
};
template <typename R, typename... P>
struct Matcher<R (*)(P...)> {
    using T = R (*)(P...);
    static void Disp() {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pointer<T>::value << '\n';
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<R(P...), T>::value << '\n';
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<R (*)(P...), T>::value
                  << '\n';
        std::cout << "Matcher matched a pointer to function\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Match(square);
    MatchPtr(square);
    Matcher<decltype(square)>::Disp();
    Matcher<decltype(&square)>::Disp();
}
```

Which outputs:

> true
> true
> false
> Match matched a function
> true
> MatchPtr matched a pointer to function
> false
> true
> false
> Matcher matched a function
> true
> false
> true
> Matcher matched a pointer to function

[LIVE](https://godbolt.org/z/YebPY6d33)

As far as I understand, the function `square` has type `int(int)`: function taking an `int` as argument and returning an `int`.
So `Match(square);` accepts it but tells me that the type of `foo` is a pointer `int(*)(int)`.
`MatchPtr(square);` behaves as I expected, `foo` being treated or converted to function to pointer.
Eventually `Matcher<decltype(square)>::Disp();` and  `Matcher<decltype(&square)>::Disp();` seem to show that `square` has indeed a type `int(int)`.
Note that removing `Matcher` specialization for pointer trigger an understandable compilation error.

Thus it's the behavior of `Match(R foo(P...))` that I don't understand: I would have expected the type of the parameter `foo` to be deduced as `int(int)` but it seems to be `int(*)(int)` why is it so and is there a syntax to obtain a function type instead (though this second question is more a rhetorical one, with few practical interest)?

related:

- specialization: [specializing for "direct" function types (as opposed to function-pointer types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995557/specializing-for-direct-function-types-as-opposed-to-function-pointer-types)
- function-to-pointer conversion: [Difference in using function type vs function pointer as C++ template function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841041/difference-in-using-function-type-vs-function-pointer-as-c-template-function-p) and [function type vs. function pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219227/function-type-vs-function-pointer-type)
- with `std::function`: [Syntax of C++ templates with function type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245235/syntax-of-c-templates-with-function-type-parameters)

Comment: there is a function type in C and C++ syntax, but there is no value of function type or an expression which would have one as a result. You can pass a pointer to function

Comment: In `Match(square)`, the function type **decays** to a pointer to a function type. See [Function-to-function-pointer "decay"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559758/function-to-function-pointer-decay). Basically, when we have a function type as function parameter it decays to a function pointer. **This is just like when we have array parameter it decays to a pointer to its element type.**

Comment: Just recall that when passing a function as a parameter, it will inevitably decay to a pointer to function.  Passing a function by value is not a thing.  Then it will all make sense.